# can't get the value returned in the API from ANDROID device

Tags: php, android, mysql

Am working on an android application. I created an API with PHP that returns a value , and am trying to get the value from my android device. but none of my attempts have worked.

Here's the code of the API.

```
<?php 
include ('conx.php');
class buildApi{

        private $CNX ;

        function __construct(){
            $this->CNX = (new Connect())->connecter();
        }

    function api($num){


        try{
            $req = $this->CNX->query("SELECT priority FROM cache where num=".$num);
            $res = $req->fetchColumn();
        } catch(PDOException $e) { die('error'.$e->getMessage());} 


            if($res != null) return $res;
            else return "Numero non autorisé ";
    }
}

if (!empty($_GET["n"])) {
  $num = intval($_GET["n"]);

  $apiV = new buildApi();
  $priority = $apiV->api($num);
  $fruits = array (
  "Numero <br>"  => $num,
  "<br> Priority <br>"  => $priority );
  echo "<br>Sortie JSON <br><br>".json_encode($fruits); 
}

?>
```

And here's the class where i send the request to the API:

```
public class NumFetch {

public static JSONObject getJSON( Context context,String num) {
    try {
        Log.i("fetch", "Priority 9bl");
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.43.90:800/cach/api.php?n="+ num);
        Log.i("fetch", "wset1 ");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader reader;
        Log.i("fetch", "wset2 ");
        InputStreamReader inStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
        Log.i("fetch", "wset2.5 ");
        reader = new BufferedReader(inStreamReader);
        Log.i("fetch", "wset3 ");
        StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer();
        String tmp = "";
        Log.i("fetch", "wset4");

        while((tmp = reader.readLine()) != null)
            json.append(tmp).append("\n");
        reader.close();

        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json.toString());

        if(data.getInt("cod") != 200) {
            return null;
        }
        Log.i("fetch", "Priority ");
        return data;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

In the log window , I get

```
03-08 15:09:56.794  17795-17795/com.example.andrei.weatherapp I/fetch﹕ Priority 9bl
03-08 15:09:56.804  17795-17795/com.example.andrei.weatherapp I/fetch﹕ wset1

03-08 15:09:56.804  17795-17795/com.example.andrei.weatherapp I/fetch﹕ wset2
```

I tried this from an other pc , and that works perfectly .

Can you please help, I'm stuck here two days now .

Comment: Does the machine running the API have access to the mysql server? Bear in mind that your android device will talk to the API, not to the database directly, or at least it should

Comment: Yes sure. I tried to get the value with the browser and it works perfectly.

Comment: Okay, so it is not a mysql problem, but a problem with your android app talking to the API. It might be wise to rephrase your question in this case.